# Выравнивание img по размеру header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

**Задравствуйте, верстаю шапку header. Изображение внутри блока header, как можно выровнить img по размеру блока header?**

[image: Зл]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, структура у вас следующая:

```
<header>
  <img src="src/images/header.jpg">
</header>
```

Во-первых, это не всегда верно. Если картинка визуально является фоновой, то она и должна быть фоновой, то есть указанной через `background-image: url("src/images/header.jpg");`. В таком случае подгон картинки осуществляется при помощи `background-size`. В качестве значения туда можно подставить значение в абсолютных/относительных единицах измерения либо специальные значения, такие как `contain` (вписать по большей стороне, не обрезать картинку, но сверху/снизу или справа/слева будет пустота) и `cover` (вписать по меньшей стороне, обрезать картинку). Выровнять такую картинку довольно легко: `background-position: center` (ну или top/bottom/left/right).

Однако, если всё же хотите оставить свою структуру, то тогда подгон осуществляется при помощи `width` и `height`, которые мы задаём `img`. Чтобы вписать картинку по ширине, сохраняя при этом пропорции, просто пишем:

```
header > img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Разумеется, пропорции можно и не сохранять, и принудительно растянуть картинку по размерам блока, но в таком случае у `header` должны быть явно прописаны `width` и `height`.